Error at child function in a Container ( mobile app flutter)
I am doing the signup screen and I have an error in the Container, I have first child function and at the second there is an error at child(Elevated Button). Any idea what I should do? Use a Scaffold? Or create another container?`
class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 300,
        
        child: Form(

             
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 30.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                  
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Nume Companie/Liber Profesionst/Client',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Antra',
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  color: Colors.black)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 40.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                     
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Email',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Antra',
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  color: Colors.black)),
                        ),
                     
           child: ElevatedButton(
           
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                )),


I try to add a padding and a sizebox but nothing worked

On Column, you need  to provide widget directly inside children and the Padding widget already have a child.
class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 300,
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 30.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Nume Companie/Liber Profesionst/Client',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Antra',
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                        color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 40.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Antra',
                        fontSize: 12.0,
                        color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                  )),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Thank you and if I want to add another child: Row after this where I should added? like after ElevatedButton

You can add after Text  widget.  You can find more on layout
